# Android Development and retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

My Question is simple i want to retrieve my github repos with the help github api using retrofit in android, So i am little confuse how to pass my github username to url i have tried but it give me error message.
This is my webservice URL for retrieving my github repos :
https://api.github.com/users/mshahzaib374/repos. Here you can see my username is **mshahzaib374**, So how can i pass my username to url as parameter.
I hope you understand my question, I am attaching code snippets and error screen please see it, Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Retrofit homepage](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) contains sample code that very similar to what you want:

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

So, to insert username in URL you have to substitute part of URL with some name in curly braces and add corresponding parameter to method marked with `@Path("<your parameter name>")` annotation.

Comment: Let me check and test it

Comment: If possible I want to add parameters using hashmap in retrofit

Comment: Path parameters can't be passed using Map, but you can use [@QueryMap](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/QueryMap.html) for query parameters and [@PartMap](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/PartMap.html) for POST request body

Comment: i tried the same code which you tell but it show me this error now

Comment: E/Fail: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: i solved the problem by replacing  Call<GithubRepos> getRepos(@Path("user") String user); to  Call<List<GithubRepos>> getRepos(@Path("user") String user);

Answer (score -1):

You can make a GET API call like this

```
GET /users/:username/repos
```

[Check this out](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories) the official GIT api documentation.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Actually I want to give parameter through hash map